# Matplotlib plot in a multiprocessing process does not show

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, process, multiprocessing

Surprisingly, I did not find a question reproducing my issue. The code snippet below does not show any figure, why is this the case and how can I get the figure to appear?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def f():
    f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5])
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = mp.Process(target=f)
    process.start()

    time.sleep(5)
    process.join()
```

Comment: Does it show without multi processing?  What backend are you trying to make this appear in?

Comment: It's with the `MacOSX` backend. And no, it looks like it does not work even without the multiprocessing. Switching to `Qt5Agg` seems to solve it. Any explanation thou?

Comment: You probably were using a non-interactive backend before you switched to Qt.

Comment: `plt.show()` should still display even if the `MacOSX` backend was not interactive, which it is according to https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/users/explain/backends.html#the-builtin-backends